# A query with primary key field used twice

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, primary-key

In my database I have two tables:

relationship table: 
`organization_id_first, organization_id_second, relationship_type`

organization table: 
`primary key = org_id ; org_id, org_name, ...`

How would I be able to join the `organization` table so that I could get the `org_name` for both organizations that have an entry in the relationship table? I don't think I can join on the same primary key. Would I have to do a subquery of some sort?

Thanks!

Comment: Primary keys are for data consistency (insert/update/delete). No need to know them then joining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i would do it in T-SQL ... just join it twice and make two different object

```
select or1.org_name, or2.org_name, rel.relationship_type from relationship  rel
   join organization  or1 on rel.organization_id_first = or1.org_id
   join organization  or2 on rel.organization_id_second = or2.org_id
```