# SQL SELECT - Chats

Tags: sql, select

I need little help with reading my "chats" SQL table.

Column:

```
Chat_ID  -  decimal(18, 0) primary key, inflexible-yes

Sent_ID  - decimal(18, 0)

Receive_ID - decimal(18, 0)

Time  - datetime

Message  - nvarchar(MAX)


Sent_ID| Receive_ID  |     Time     |     Message
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  1    |    2     | 11/21/2015 10:00 | Hey! test
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  2    |    1     | 11/21/2015 10:50 | Hi!  respond 
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  1    |    2     | 11/21/2015 10:51 | respond 3
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  2    |    1     | 11/21/2015 11:05 | respond final 
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  1    |    3     | 11/21/2015 11:51 | Message 1
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  3    |    1     | 11/21/2015 12:05 | Message 2 
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  1    |    3     | 11/21/2015 12:16 | Message Final
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  4    |    1     | 11/21/2015 12:25 | New message 1
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
```

**How to get...(last message with each user?)**

```
Sent_ID| Receive_ID  |     Time     |     Message
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  2    |    1     | 11/21/2015 11:05 | respond final 
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  1    |    3     | 11/21/2015 12:16 | Message Final
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
  4    |    1     | 11/21/2015 12:25 | New message 1
-------+----------+------------------+-----------------
```

You notice that i need something like: MAX(Time),  WHERE (Sent_ID=@Sent_ID or Receive_ID=@Receive_ID)  in these case........... Sent_ID=1..... Receive_ID=1
**to simplify**: WHERE (Sent_ID=1 or Receive_ID=1)

Thank you....

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I understand now that you want to get the latest message between two users regardless if it is sent or received. If that's the case, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482883)</kbd>

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn =    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY
                        CASE
                            WHEN Sent_ID > Receive_ID THEN Receive_ID
                            ELSE Sent_ID
                        END,
                        CASE
                            WHEN Sent_ID > Receive_ID THEN Sent_ID
                            ELSE Receive_ID
                        END
                    ORDER BY Time DESC  
                )
    FROM chats
    WHERE
        Sent_ID = 1
        OR Receive_ID = 1
)
SELECT
    Sent_ID, Receive_ID, Time, Message
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

What the above query does is to partition the chat messages by the lower ID first, and then the higher ID. This way, you ensure that you have distinct combination of IDs.

---

First, you need to get the last message sent by the user. And the `UNION` it to the last messages received by the user from each of the other users.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM chats c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Sent_ID, MAX(Time) AS MaxTime
    FROM chats
    WHERE Sent_ID = 1
    GROUP BY Sent_ID
) t
    ON t.Sent_ID = c.Sent_ID
    AND t.MaxTime = c.Time

UNION ALL

SELECT c.*
FROM chats c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Sent_ID, MAX(Time) AS MaxTime
    FROM chats
    WHERE Receive_ID = 1
    GROUP BY Sent_ID
) t
    ON t.Sent_ID = c.Sent_ID
    AND t.MaxTime = c.Time
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482878)</kbd>

Comment: I will test this on my database. But when I see your ONLINE DEMO not working properly. Repeating columns 1 and 3... But I will test...

Comment: @Milan, Oh, I misunderstood your problem. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will test.

Comment: Update version working! I don't know why it's just too advanced SQL coding for me :-D  If I can ask you for another favor? How to join another table "Users" to get Names, ( join by Sent_ID =Users_ID and Receive_ID=Users_ID)

Comment: If you didn't managed to do the join ... check answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557789/a-query-with-primary-key-field-used-twice/35557836#35557836

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with rows are not being unique, as for SQL server conversation between UserID (1 and 2) is not same as conversation between UserID (2 and 1), SQL server see it as a different things.

So my advice would be to create another table named something like

```
create table Conversation (ConvoID int, FromID int, ToID int)

insert into COnversation (ConvoID, FromID, ToID)
values (1, 1, 2),
       (1, 2, 1),
       (2, 1, 3),
       (2, 3, 1)
```

And then you can join Conversation table on your "Chat" table, and go with group by ConvoID and max date ... because that is only way to make chat between two users to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select c.* from

 ( select User1id,User2id,max(time) as newtime
  from
    ( select 
      case when sent_id < receive_id then sent_id else receive_id
     end as User1id,
      case when sent_id > receive_id then sent_id else receive_id
     end as User2id,
     time
     from chats where (Sent_ID = 1 or Receive_ID = 1)
    ) temp
    group by User1id,User2id
 )t1
  inner join chats c on 
  t1.newtime = c.time
```